# Elasticsearch NEST How to combine multiple queries with raw queries

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to combine multiple queries into a single boolean query but the query generated is empty for the queries that are raw.

This is my method call

```
ConvertQueryToESD("{\"term\":\"fieldname\":\"value\"}"
                  ,null
                  ,a range filter)
    .From(0)
    .Take(50)
    .SortMulti(a sort)
```

This is the method

```
 internal SearchDescriptor<T> ConvertQueryToESD<T>(string queryString, string filterId, List<QueryContainer> filters) where T : class
    {
        var filterQueryString = GetFilter(filterId);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterQueryString))
        {
            var qd = new QueryDescriptor<T>();
            filters.Add(qd.Raw(filterQueryString));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString))
        {
            var qd = new QueryDescriptor<T>();
            filters.Add(qd.Raw(queryString));
        }
        var sd = new SearchDescriptor<T>();
        sd.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(filters.ToArray())));
        return sd;
    }
```

My resulting query is

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "startTimeLocal": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startTimeLocal": {
              "gte": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "lte": "2015-12-22T16:28:22"
            }
          }
        },
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `{}` is where I would expect to see the raw term query. Why is the raw query not being serialized in to the SearchDescriptor? I have inspected the SearchDescriptor and the field is populated before the search is ran. I have also tested only adding the raw string term query without the range filter and the search descriptor serializes correctly.

Addendum

```
private string GetFilter(string filterId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterId))
        {
            return null;
        }
        var response = _elasticClient.Get<FilterMapping>(filterId);
        ThrowIfNotSuccessfull(response.ConnectionStatus);
        return response.Source?.QueryString;
    }
```

Comment: Would you also be able to show what `GetFilter(filterId);` does (simplified)?

Comment: GetFilter just fetches a document that has a query string.